# run build from create-react-app on local machine

Tags: reactjs

A have create-react-app application. 
I want to run production version on my local machine.
I have made 'npm run build' and than 'npx webpack' 
(for addition info i use react-app-rewired in that poject to config proxy for devserver) and have next mistake:

```
ERROR in ./src/index.js 13:2
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (13:2)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| 
| ReactDOM.render(
>   <Provider store={store}>
|     <App />
|   </Provider>,
```

'serve -s build' do not work in my case:

```
zsh: command not found: serve
```

What should i do to run production build on my local?
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

A better way to handle this would not be to install a new global, but use `npx` to run `serve`:

```
npx run serve -s build
```

Answer (score -1):

Please check if you have serve installed globally on local machine or not.
If not, then follow below commands:

```
npm install -g serve
serve -s build
```

If this doesn't work then remove the build, close the command prompt and again run the *npm run build* command and serve it.

Also, there is no preset & babel-loader in the application so install the dependency and add loader in the application.

```
npm install babel-preset-es2015
```

Configure the babel-loader

```
{
    test: /\.jsx?$/,
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    query: {
        presets: ['es2015']
    }
}
```

Comment: I have resovled it. 
I needed to ran 'serve -s build' but my serve were installed globaly via sudo and this is metter why it was not work. I nedded  to change directory where npm installs global packages  (https://github.com/sindresorhus/guides/blob/master/npm-global-without-sudo.md)
and 'serve-s build' command work!

Comment: Great. Happy Coding!!

Comment: Why would you suggest to install globals when OP is using `npx` to to call `webpack`?